# Replication - Issues with turning on SQL Agent on Local Machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to learn more about replication and want to turn it on for my local copy of SQL2008.  I watched one video that said I can create a publication on my local machine and then replicate to a different database on the same machine.  Their example works and I want to try it.

Is there anything I should be concerned about regarding turning on SQL Agent?

Thanks in advance,

Randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done replication (for test purposes) on a laptop with 2 GB of RAM and it has worked perfectly.

I have not encountered any issues with turning SQL Agent ON either.

Comment: Thanks.  I turned it on and replicated a database.  Everything appears to be working fine.